# Android No View Found for Fragment after Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am getting an error when my device orientation changes. Everything works fine up until the orientation changes.

I have a fragment (TrapCheckContainerFragment) which contains a FrameLayout that is used to hold another fragment (TrapCheckFragment). The TrapCheckFragment is created in the onCreateView method of TrapCheckContainerFragment and is placed into the FrameLayout using a FragmentTransaction.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trap_check_container, container, false);

    TrapCheckFragment fragment = new TrapCheckFragment();

    ReplaceFragment(R.id.trapCheckHolder, fragment, false, feature.trapUniqueID.toString());

    return rootView;
}

private void ReplaceFragment(int idToReplace, Fragment newFragment, boolean addToBackStack, String tag){

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(idToReplace, newFragment, tag);

    if(addToBackStack){
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }

    transaction.commit();
}
```

This all works fine until I rotate the device. None of my code is called as far as I can tell but for some reason the FragmentManager is not able to find the view called trapCheckHolder which is the FrameLayout used to hold the child fragment. If I remove the call to ReplaceFragment then everything works fine when I rotate the device.

The logcat message:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.redacted.appname, PID: 29396
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.redacted.appname/com.redacted.appname.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0042 (com.redacted.appname:id/trapCheckHolder) for fragment TrapCheckFragment{64fa6b18 #4 id=0x7f0a0042 10236}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3724)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0042 (com.redacted.appname:id/trapCheckHolder) for fragment TrapCheckFragment{64fa6b18 #4 id=0x7f0a0042 10236}
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
    ... 10 more
```

I have tried setting setRetainInstance to both true and false for this and the parent Fragment but this hasn't made any difference. Is there anything obviously wrong with what I am doing here? And is there any way to force a new TrapCheckFragment to be created rather than trying to show the old one which seems to be causing this issue?

I can provide more information about any of the code or errors if requried.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `onCreateViewMethod` was causing issues; it must return null if the container is null:

Do something like that to check the null and re create the view :

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (rootView == null) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment 
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        } else { 
            // Do not inflate the layout again. 
            // The returned View of onCreateView will be added into the fragment. 
            // However it is not allowed to be added twice even if the parent is same. 
            // So we must remove rootView from the existing parent view group 
            // (it will be added back). 
            ((ViewGroup)rootView.getParent()).removeView(rootView);
        } 
        return rootView;
```

Please check, and let me know if it works.

Comment: How should I be getting _rootView in this example? I tried both storing the created rootView and also calling getView() but the first returns null from getParent() and the second is null when the orientation changes.

Comment: rootView is just a class variable like : `View rootView;` its always null when first time fragment is created.

Comment: It seems that rootView.getParent() is returning null. I'm having trouble debugging this as the app crashes without an error message if the debugger is attached and does not hit any breakpoints after the device rotation has happened.